# Bash file to compile multiple documents using different variables from CSV in separate folders?

Tags: compiling, automation, letters, bash, command-line

There is probably a better way to do this, but this is my MWE attempt and I cannot get it to work.

I want to compile multiple form letters from a `.csv` file like below:

```
 company,   dept
World of Cheese Inc,    Accounting Department
Big Ham LLC,    Tax Division
```

That will feed into

```latex
\documentclass{letter}

\renewcommand{\department}{}
\renewcommand{\company}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}

Hello,
I am writing \company{} to inquire about the \department.

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I want to keep the main `.tex` file in a folder, then create a subfolder named after each company which the LaTeX document will compile in (ultimately there will be several documents to compile in the folder).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Name of the csv file to loop through.
INPUTFILE="mwe.csv"

while IFS=$',' read -r schl dept

echo "starting $company"
echo "for $dept"

# 1 make new directory with school name 
    mkdir -p "$company"  

cp lettermwe.tex  "$company"
cd "$company"

# 2 build document   
pdflatex -jobname=mwe_"$company"  -no-shell-escape '\def\newcommand{\company}{$company} \def\newcommand{\department{$dept} \input{lettermwe.tex}'  &

cd -
done < "$INPUTFILE"
```

I get this error:

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

<*> \def\newcommand{\company}{company} 
\def\newcommand{\department{dept^^M}\in..
```

First-time asker, so I'll be happy to clarify.  Or not sure if this is better suited in the linux/bash stack.

Also if this can be done within LaTeX I'm open to suggestions.  But I do ultimately want multiple documents for each company in its folder.

Comment: Do you really need many files in different folders? If you use `datatool` you can easily create a single pdf with one page for each csv entry.

Comment: I think that would be the simplest for two reasons.  Distribution, because there will be several different documents that need to be attached separately electronically later instead of printed out like mailed form letters.  Also, the ability to tailor some prose in specific .tex files would be desirable.

Comment: By the way, it is easy to split a pdf into pages.

Comment: you have `\def\newcommand{\company}` which redefines `\newcommand` so it makes the text `company` and no longer defines commands, that will completely break latex. use `\def` or `\newcommand` not both!!!!

Comment: I'd use `textmerg` and then split with `pdftk`, then script creation of directories and movement of PDFs, if required.